# Bootstrap dropdown menu in small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a dropdown list (with 15-20 items) on `navbar`. All the dropdown items are not visible on mobile phone.

I have tried below inside `bootstrap.css`:

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
        overflow-y: visible;
        overflow-y: auto;          
    }
```

[image]

It's not working.(**Bootstrap v3.0.3**)

**HTML:**

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>                        
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="templatemo-nav-bar">                        
                    <div class="navbar-left" style="width: 98%; float: left;">                            
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="dropdownState">                                
                            <li class="dropdown" style="margin-top: 4px; background-color: #5e8fed; color: #fff; border-top: 1px solid #02215b; border-bottom: 1px solid #02215b;">                                    
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;StateName <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                     //loop here
                                   <li><a data-id="@item.Value" class="lnkChangeState" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;@item.Text</a></li> 
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>                 
            </div>              
        </div>          
    </div>
```

How can I make it working on small devices as well?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you.

Comment: I have added the HTML

Comment: Thanks. Are you using basic bootstrap css and js too?

Comment: Yes it is basic bootstrap. Additional js used in `stickUp.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm updating my answer! It helped to see your actual code.

Since your menu drop down is fixed position and overflow hidden you'll never see the entire menu if it needs more screen room than it has.

You need to update this class with the following attributes:

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
overflow: scroll;
```

}

and do not call these attributes:

```
max-height: none !important;
height: auto !important;
```

This makes the drop down menu scrollable. Adjust the height with media queries if you like, but it will work now.

Comment: Post a link to a live version of your code. Can't debug yours because it has back end calls and added js classes. Removing the overflow attributes works for me in the code example I posted. What's not working?

Answer (score 1):

I have made it to work. Change the following styles:

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow: hidden; 
    max-height: none !important; 
    height: auto !important;
}
```

to

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    /* max-height: none !important; */
    height: auto !important;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bhai..;)